# Creating Global document in PDFSharp

Tags: vb.net, pdfsharp

Not sure if this is specific to PDFSharp, but I have created a PDF document in the main form of a VB.Net project as shown below, and I want to make it global so that Subs in other modules can access it and create new pages and write to those pages. Thanks a lot for any assistance. I tried declaring "doc" as public, but that did not work.

This is the code I have:

[Main Form]

```
Public Class Form1

    Public Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim doc As PdfDocument = New PdfDocument
        doc.Info.Title = "Created with PDFsharp"

        Output.Addpage()

        Dim filename As String = "NewFile.pdf"
        doc.Save(filename)

        Process.Start(filename)

    End Sub
End Class
```

Output Module

```
Public Sub Addpage()

    page = doc.AddPage
        
    Using gfx As XGraphics = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page)

        gfx.DrawRectangle(TablePen, dispLeftMarg - 4, dispTopMarg - 8, dispallowedL + 8, dispallowedH + 12)

    End Using
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to make `doc` public in VB.NET.

In this case, I would not do it anyway.

It's cleaner to pass the `doc` as a parameter in the call to `Public Sub Addpage()`.

`Public Sub Addpage(ByVal doc As PdfDocument)` should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you for your response. That is what I am doing right now, but was hoping not to need to add that argument at every call to every Sub that adds a page and writes on it.

Comment: Add the field `doc` to the class outside the click event handler and make it public. Or make a property (a private field with a public getter). That's a big hack as the property will always exist, but it only has a meaningful value while the click event is being executed. Call `doc = new PdfDocument` at the start of the click event and `doc = nothing` at the end. I would pass `doc` as a parameter to get cleaner code.